# TupleQueryResult (result.hasNext()) decreasing performance

Tags: java, iteration, sparql, resultset

I am using SPARQL queries to get RDF using java.

My SPARQL query is running fine and I get the resultset and  when I started `while` loop, the `hasnext()` method decreasing the performance by taking too much time even for less records.

I printed the logs and found `while (thisTermDataResult.hasNext()) {` is taking nearly 11000 ms which is not at all acceptable.

SPARQL is also running fine. So what exactly doing `hasNext()` method from `TupleQueryResult` class. And do we have any alternative to iterate resultset of `TupleQueryResult`

I searched a lot on the internet for solution but no luck found.

```
thisTermDataTupleQuery = conn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, thisTermDataQuery);
thisTermDataResult = thisTermDataTupleQuery.evaluate();
log.debug("#PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched at = "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));


if (null != thisTermDataResult) {
    log.debug("#PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 1 = "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));
    while (thisTermDataResult.hasNext()) {
        log.debug("#PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 2 = "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));
        Map<String, Object> currentRecord = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        log.debug("#PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 3 = "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));
        BindingSet current = thisTermDataResult.next();
        log.debug("#PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 4 = "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));
        //logic
    }
}
```

**Tha logs I have printed**

```
13:39:18.288 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# created a connection at = 1551
13:39:18.297 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched at = 1560
13:39:18.297 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 1 = 1560
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 2 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 3 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 4 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 5 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 6 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 7 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 8 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 9 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 10 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 11 = 11648
13:39:28.385 DEBUG  c.l.u.p.plc.services.PLCServiceImpl - #PERF-getHouseAssessmentReview# thisTermDataTupleQuery# data fetched 12 = 11648
```

Comment: I guess you have to understand that the returned result is first just an iterator resp. cursor over the final resultset. That means, the resultset isn't computed completely but just on-demand, by calling `next`. Moreover, if the resultset is large or the query is expensive, this can be indeed a time-consuming task. Unfortunately, you haven't shown details about query + the dataset nur whether you're using the in-memory triple store or a remote triple store. Thus, no advice for improvement (if possible) can't be given

Comment: Like @AKSW mentioned: a `TupleQueryResult` is an iterator that is evaluated lazily. Calling `next()` kicks off the actual query execution. If your query is expensive that can indeed take a while. 11 seconds seems a lot but it's impossible to guess at the cause without knowing more about the query, the data, and the type of repository that you're using. Please [edit] your question to add the necessary details.